# Action Cable subscription not taken into account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am working on a real-time chat app and I can't get Action Cable working. I followed the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) but I must be missing something.

Here is my code :

```
  #groups_channel.rb
    class GroupsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
     def subscribed
       stream_from "group_#{params[:group_id]}"
     end
    end



#<!-- app/views/groups/show.html.erb -->
<!-- ... -->
 <% content_for :after_js do %>
    <script>
    App['group_<%= @group.id %>'] = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
  { channel: 'GroupsChannel', group_id: <%= @group.id %> },
  { received: (data) => { 
        const messagesContainer = document.querySelector('.messages-tab-content');
        messagesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.message_box);
        scrollLastMessageIntoView();

    })
  </script>
<% end %>


   # app/models/message.rb
    class Message < ApplicationRecord
      after_create :broadcast_message
      # ...
     def broadcast_message
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("group_#{self.group.id}", {
      message_partial: ApplicationController.renderer.render(
         partial: "groups/message_box",
        locals: { message: self }
      ),
    })
     end
    end
```

Here is what I have in my console. 
It seems there are no subscription even though I force the cable subscription the line above.

[image]

Any leads would be really helpful.